# Multiple keyword results using PHP simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have set of keywords which i like to parse through simple html dom & retrieve the scrapped data for all the keywords at the same page & at same time. Problem is that the simple html dom is retrieving data only for the final keyword in the list and not the other keywords. I would really me thankful if anyone can help me sort this issue for me. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$keywords = "math,chemistry,science";

$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
echo $keyword.'<br>';
}

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://www.tutorvista.com/search/'.$keyword);

$i = 1;
foreach($html->find('div[style=padding:20px; border-top:thin solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom:none;]') as $element) {
foreach($element->find('div[class=entry-abstract]') as $div) 
{
    $title[$i] = $div->plaintext.'<br><br>';
}
   $i++;
}
print_r($title);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include all codes after first foreach:

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
echo $keyword.'<br>';

//include other code here 

//..
print_r($title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$keyword only has the value of the last element processed by the foreach loop. The operations for each keyword must be into the foreach loop:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$keywords = "math,chemistry,science";

$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    echo $keyword.'<br>';

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.tutorvista.com/search/'.$keyword);

    $i = 1;
    foreach($html->find('div[style=padding:20px; border-top:thin solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom:none;]') as $element)
    {
        foreach($element->find('div[class=entry-abstract]') as $div) 
        {
            $title[$i] = $div->plaintext.'<br><br>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    print_r($title);
}

?>
```